# How do I check if any textarea is empty?

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 textareas with a submit button that I would like to be enabled only when each of the 3 textareas has some content.
Here is what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/2wkb9wmq/5/

HTML

```
<body>
  <form>
    <p>First</p>
    <textarea name="first" id="first" cols="12" rows="2"></textarea>
    <p>Second</p>
    <textarea name="second" id="second" cols="12" rows="2"></textarea>
    <p>Third</p>
    <textarea name="third" id="third" cols="12" rows="2"></textarea>
    <button type='button' disabled>Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="button"]').attr('disabled', true);
    $('textarea').on('keyup',function() {

      $("textarea").each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() != "") {

          $('input[type="button"]').attr('disabled', false);

        } else {

          $('input[type="button"]').attr('disabled' , true);
        }  
      });    
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a variable and set it, if *one textarea is not filled*:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var button = $('button');
  var textareas = $('textarea');

  textareas.on("keyup", function() {
    var disabled = false;
    textareas.each(function() {
      if (!$.trim($(this).val())) {
         disabled = true; 
      }
    });
    button.attr('disabled', disabled);
  });    

});
```

In addition i would use `!$.trim($(this).val())` to check whether the textare is empty. This also disallows empty strings.
If empty strings are allowed, only check `!$(this).val()`.

Your updated jsfilddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/2wkb9wmq/8/